# WPF Localization file folder

Tags: wpf, localization, directory

I have a WPF application with localization. In my project file (.csproj) I have added a string:

```
<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>
```

Now the problem is - when I compile the default localization (**en-US** folder) is always put to the root of $(OutDir) of the project.

Question: how do I move this directory into a subfolder (say, **$(OutDir)localized\en-US**)?